# Is there already a Redis data access framework for Dart?

Tags: redis, dart, dart-io

My server-side code runs on [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) and currently uses [Redis](http://redis.io/) as a data store via [redis_client](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redis_client).

Mostly, I'm persisting primitive data types such as integers and strings. However, I also have a handful of business objects like *User*, and ideally I'd like to store those in Redis as well.

Of course, Redis is a key-value store and not a full-fledged document database like MongoDB. So I started writing my own serialization and persistence logic - for example, a simple getter for *User*:

```dart
  import 'dart:convert';

  ...

  Future<User> GetUser(String userGuid)
  {
    var userKey = "userGuid:" + userGuid.toString();
    return redisClient.get(userKey).then((String value) {
      return new User.fromJSON(value);      
    });      
  }
```

Before I continue hand-crafting the entire persistence logic for all my business entities - is there already some sort of Redis/Dart data access package out there I should be aware of, similar to e.g. [redis_orm](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/redis_orm) (Ruby)?

If not, I'll probably write my own.

(Don't wanna call it ORM because, well, Redis != relational - but effectively that's what I'm looking for)

Comment: I don't know any Dart (yet) and I'm not familiar with OM frameworks for it and Redis... but if you're gonna get your hands dirty and code it yourself, make sure you check Redis' [Hashes](http://redis.io/commands/#hash) for a quick way to store JSON-like objects.

Comment: Even an Object to Hash or JSON to Hash lib could work. ORM would be pretty though. ;p

Answer (score 2):

We're using Java Hibernate + Dart at work,

I made an open source library for the client for this : https://github.com/frankpepermans/dorm

The server-side implementation is not open source however, Hibernate is not a requirement and any ORM type would do, the client communicates via JSON, so you'll need an adapter that works with JSON data and can handle/receive cyclic references (via Dorm, you can use pointers inside the JSON structure to specify a cyclic reference).

The server would also need to generate Dart class files that represent the entities.

But you can have for example :
- composite keys
- entity inheritance
- custom handling of data types (i.e. DateTime)
- custom data types (i.e. everything is Observable, lists are ObservableList by default, but you can tell the deserializer to use a custom List type if needed)
- supports annotations